# php - failed opening include_once with session

Tags: php, session, random, include

I want to randomly include a html file when surfed to my .php file.
I don't want that the same page can be showed twice after eachother when refreshing.

I thought I could achieve this using sessions but I seem to get some errors at certain times on rule 28 (include_once($htmls[$rand]);):

```
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\Roderik\Documents\Casimir\root\final.php on line 28

Warning: include_once(C:\Users\Roderik\Documents\Casimir\root): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\Roderik\Documents\Casimir\root\final.php on line 28

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Roderik\Documents\Casimir\root\final.php on line 28
```

I am using USB-webserver for testing this.

my code:

```
session_start();

global $htmls;
global $arrlength;
//get all .html's withing ./pages
$htmls = glob('./pages/*.html');
$arrlength = count($htmls) - 1 ;


if (isset($_SESSION['rand'])) {

    $session_rand = $_SESSION['rand'];
    $rand = rand(0, $arrlength);

    if($rand !== $session_rand)
    {
        $_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;
        include_once($htmls[$rand]);

    }
    else
    {

        $rand = getNewRandom($session_rand, $arrlength);
        $_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;
        include_once($htmls[$rand]);

    }

}
else
{
    $rand = rand(0, $arrlength);
    $_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;
    include_once($htmls[$rand]);

}

function getNewRandom($exception, $arrlength)
{

    $rand = rand(0, $arrlength);
    if($rand == $exception)
    {
        getNewRandom($exception, $arrlength);
    }
    else
    {
        return $rand;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over complicating things.  The following will ensure that a file is not included twice in a row.

```
// Files
$htmls = glob('test/*.html');
// Get the key of the previously included file
$previous = false;
if ( isset($_SESSION['rand']) ) {
    $previous = $_SESSION['rand'];  
}
// If a file was previously included, remove it from the pool
if ( $previous !== false && isset($htmls[$previous]) ) {
    unset($htmls[$previous]);
}
// Get a random key from available files
$key = $_SESSION['rand'] = array_rand($htmls);
// File to include
$include = $htmls[$key];
```

Comment: That was a lot easier, thanks!
I didn't even know about the array_rand function's existence.

Answer (score 1):

As the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\Roderik\Documents\Casimir\root\final.php on line 28
```

says, the `$rand` you're using as index in `$htmls[$rand]` is undefined, and returns a null, which is treated as an empty string in `include()`, so you're effectively running

```
include('')
```

Do a `var_dump($htmls)` and `echo $rand` immediately before your `include()` calls and see what you ARE trying to use.

Comment: the array printed just fine but $rand was empty at some times...
Changed my getNewRandom() function by

function getNewRandom($exception, $arrlength)
 {

  $rand = rand(0, $arrlength);
  while($rand == $exception) {$rand = rand(0,$arrlength);}
  return $rand;
 }

and even then it didn't work at some times but it returned a value always.

It seemed usbwebserver couldn't handle my requests (at some times it just printed the routing table).
When hosted on my webspace it works just fine, thanks for the tips though!